# Copy DB2 schema across different databases and subnets

Tags: bash, shell, db2

I want an overall better way to copy all the tables and their data from one production database schema and put it into a dev database schema on a different database in a different subnet using bash for unloads and loads.
It is important that the schema name on the dev database is and can be different.
Table structure for both schemas is the same, only the database name, schema name and data changes.

It is important that the solution requires minimum manual manipulation. Copying files across manually is acceptable but editing file contents to change data is not, unless this can be scripted to do automatically.

Currently we run a very long series of scripted exports for each table individually to ixf lobs, followed by a very long series of carefully placed scripted loads, being careful to load the data in order, parents before child.

Unload example:

```
export to CLIENT.ixf of ixf lobs to $LOCATION lobfile CLIENT_lobs modified by lobsinfile   select * from CLIENT;
```

Load example:

```
load from CLIENT.ixf of ixf lobs from $LOCATION modified by lobsinfile replace into CLIENT statistics no copy no  indexing mode autoselect allow no access check pending cascade deferred;
```

I have looked at db2move, but I cannot find how to specify database and schema name during load as it appears to only be supported in the unload/export.

db2look looks promising, but does this export the data too or just the table names?

Comment: What is your definition of "overall better way" ?   What is broken with your current solution? What is the true motivation for copying production data to non-prod environments?

Comment: Copying production data to development is mainly used to help identify and fix user errors. An Overall better way would be a simpler or cleaner solution. Perhaps there is a db2 tool that already does this? Ideally I don't want to have to change the script everytime a new table is added.